# Yocto using external toolchain encounter external_linaro_toolchain_version_handler error

Tags: toolchain, openembedded

I use a external pre-build binary toolchain got from freescale, and follow the instructions list in [linaro wik](https://wiki.linaro.org/KenWerner/Sandbox/OpenEmbedded-Core#Linaro_binary_toolchain). Follow that directions, I add the meta-linaro(master branch) layer to my conf/local.conf in front of the openembedded/meta layer, and add the `EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN` and `TCMODE` `GCCVERSION` variable as below:

```
GCCVERSION = "linaro-4.6"
SDKGCCVERSION = "linaro-4.6"

EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN = "/extdisk/yocto/88/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2"
TCMODE = "external-linaro"

IMAGE_LINGUAS = ""
LIMIT_BUILT_LOCALES = "POSIX"

DEFAULTTUNE_qemuarmv7a = "armv7athf-neon"
```

And my toolchian version detail information is:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=./prebuilt/toolchains/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/hexiongjun/SmartAuto/prebuilt/toolchains/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /work/build/.build/src/gcc-linaro-4.6-2011.06-0/configure --build=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/work/fsl-linaro-toolchain-2.13 --with-sysroot=/work/fsl-linaro-toolchain-2.13/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/multi-libs --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-pkgversion='Freescale MAD -- Linaro 2011.07 -- Built at 2011/08/10 09:20' --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libssp --with-gmp=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-mpfr=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-mpc=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-ppl=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-cloog=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-libelf=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm -L/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static/lib -lpwl' --enable-threads=posix --enable-target-optspace --enable-plugin --enable-multilib --with-local-prefix=/work/fsl-linaro-toolchain-2.13/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/multi-libs --disable-nls --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --with-system-zlib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.2 20110630 (prerelease) (Freescale MAD -- Linaro 2011.07 -- Built at 2011/08/10 09:20)
```

When I using `bitbake -v core-image-minimal` to build image, error occurs:

```
$ bitbake -v core-image-minimal
Pseudo is not present but is required, building this first before the main build
ERROR: Execution of event handler 'external_linaro_toolchain_version_handler' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "external_linaro_toolchain_version_handler(e)", line 8, in external_linaro_toolchain_version_handler(e=<bb.event.ConfigParsed object at 0x17ed4d0>)
  File "external-linaro-toolchain-versions.inc", line 4, in elt_get_main_version(d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x17ed390>)
IndexError: list index out of range

ERROR: Layer 'linaro' depends on layer 'networking-layer', but this layer is not enabled in your configuration

Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I don`t know what's going wrong, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar message

```
Summary: There were 3 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
vmb@mercury:~/virtualbox-home-drive/vmb/tci6638/oe-layersetup-mcsdk/build$ bitbake
Pseudo is not present but is required, building this first before the main build
ERROR: Execution of event handler 'external_linaro_toolchain_version_handler' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "external_linaro_toolchain_version_handler(e)", line 12, in external_linaro_toolchain_version_handler(e=<bb.event.ConfigParsed object at 0x1e99590>)
  File "external-linaro-toolchain-versions.inc", line 4, in elt_get_gdb_version(d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x1e0c190>)
NameError: global name 'CmdError' is not defined

Loading cache: 100% |##########################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 34 entries from dependency cache.
/home/vmb/tools/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory                                                                                        | ETA:  --:--:--
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/vmb/tci6638/oe-layersetup-mcsdk/sources/meta-arago/meta-arago-extras/recipes-core/meta/external-arago-sdk-toolchain.bb: Failure expanding variable ARG_VER_GDB[:=], expression was ${@arg_get_gdb_version(d)} which triggered exception IndexError: list index out of range
/home/vmb/tools/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: Command execution failed: Exited with 1
```

It turned out it was the very last error that was the cause of my problems... I needed to install the ncurses libs

Your output has one line that might be the issue

```
ERROR: Layer 'linaro' depends on layer 'networking-layer', but this layer is not enabled in your configuration
```